# Best Advertising Platform on iOS

Tags: ios, ads

I have added iAd to my app but I have read that is not the best advertising platform on iOS. Must I change it to another option like AdWhirl or the Google Ads SDK for iOS. Whats the most lucrative option? (My app is a tourist guide)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think AdWhirl is a good idea and is what I use in my ad supported apps. It allows you to use most of the main advertising companies and means you can switch between the different ones without creating new builds of your app.

Personally I place iAd as the first priory as the rates are the best but the fill rates are often pretty low (and non-existent in many countries). AdMob is second and I used "house ads" third.

The answer for you probably depends on where your users are and exactly what your app does. But that's exactly why AdWhirl is a good idea, you can change the ratios as often as you want.

(One thing to consider if you're expecting tourists to use it: will they have data switched on? You're not going to get many click's if your users are not online!)

Comment: Thanks for your response Stephen. The users of my app will be normally not foreign people (they must have the data switched on). I have registered me on AdWhirl an hour ago and I have not received any mail from them. It takes so much time normally?

Comment: I don't remember to be honest -- it was a while ago now -- but I don't recall any specific problems.